# Wordpress, get configured first day of week option

Tags: php, wordpress

Clients can freely configure what day they consider the week to start on. I can't figure out how to access this configuration information however.

[image]

```
$calendar = IntlCalendar::createInstance(NULL, get_locale());
$calendar->getFirstDayOfWeek();
```

The above is the best I've been able to find, but that only takes what is officially considered the first day of the week from the locale; not what the client has configured themselves.

Anyone know how I can access the value of this field?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/

Comment: @CBroe what's the option's name?

Comment: `start_of_week`

Comment: @CBroe Yep that works :) get_option('start_of_week')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a site option, so you can use [`get_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) to fetch the value.

The name of this particular option, as mentioned on the linked page, is `start_of_week`.